# I was expecting I would get only one line of result, but I got three lines of results

Tags: javascript

Currently I am working on a practicing code, which is generating slot machine feature(very basic). And here is the code

```
function randMax(max) {
  return Math.trunc(1E9 * Math.random()) % max;
}
var reel = {
  symbols: ["X", "Y", "Z", "W", "$", "*", "<", "@"],
  spin() {
    if (this.position == null) {
      this.position = randMax(this.symbols.length - 1);
    }
    this.position = (this.position + 100 + randMax(100)) % this.symbols.length;
  },
  display() {
    if (this.position == null) {
      this.position = randMax(this.symbols.length - 1);
    }
    return this.symbols[this.position];
  }
}

var slotMachine = {
  reels: [
    Object.create(reel),
    Object.create(reel),
    Object.create(reel)
  ],
  spin() {
    this.reels.forEach(function spinReel(reel) {
      reel.spin();
    });
  },
  display() {
    var lines = [];
    for (
      let linePos = -1; linePos <= 1; linePos++
    ) {
      let line = this.reels.map(
        function getSlot(reel) {
          var slot = Object.create(reel);
          slot.position = (reel.symbols.length + reel.position + linePos) % reel.symbols.length;
          return reel.display.call(slot);
        }
      );
      lines.push(line.join(" | "));
    }
    return lines.join("\n");
  }
};
slotMachine.spin();
console.log(slotMachine.display());
```

The code is simple, `var reel` *(line 4)* generates random **this.position** *(line 7)* value by using `randMax(max)` *(line 1)* function. By using **this.position** it gets an element from **symbols** *(line5)*.
So in `var slotmachine` I am using `Object.create(reel)` *(line 17)* feature to access `var reel`*(as I know this is a way to get **Prototypes** so that I can access certain property features right?)*

And in below  `var slotMachine` is using `for` loop to generate three random elements from symbols array.

The question is, when I am seeing this part *(from line 33~42)* ,

```
...
for ( 
let linePos = -1; linePos <= 1; linePos++ 
) { 
    let line = this.reels.map(...
```

In this **for** loop, I was assuming it is going to get 3 elements from **symbols** array. Since there is only **linePos** in this `for` loop so I expected this loop will end after **linePos** got value of 1 *(started in -1)* , so only three numbers would be generated.

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node slotmachine.js
< | * | @
```

This is what I expected, but I got

```
PS C:\Users\leePC\babel\public\src> node slotmachine.js
< | * | @
@ | < | X
X | @ | Y
```

all three lines. This is a desired outcome but I am still not sure why it got all the three lines! I was thinking I should do loop three times but by doing one loop it generates 9 items. How could this happen? Did I miss something or any other stuff that I am using but still not noticing?

Comment: `reels.map` loops through the 3 objects in `reels`, adding a symbol each time, and the `for` loop repeats all this 3 times

Comment: so is this a default feature from ``.map``? or it is beacuse I use ``Object.create(reel)`` three times?

Comment: In the function `getSlot` you reuse the name `reel` as a parameter, which may be adding to the confusion. You may find it easier to reason about the code if you use more standard methods of declaring objects based on a prototype - like using a `function` or `class` declaration to create the prototype and `new Reel()` to create a new object from it.

Comment: It's because `reels` is an array containing three objects and `map` iterates over each of the items in an array, applying a function to each in turn and returning an array of the function's return values

Comment: ohhhhh I see. So that is why it wokrs all the tree times lin ``reels``

Comment: Does your definition of reel.spin work? Shouldn't it be spin: function () {} and not spin() {}

Comment: Oh yes! It works fine! I guess it abstract some stuffs